# How do I insert one value into one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a value from a field on front end application that is connected to the DB. The thing is I would like to insert the single value entered into One column in a table that has multiple columns.

Comment: When inserting a record, what value should the other columns assume? Simply NULL?

Comment: @kizito: Youre question is extremely vague. Please specify the type of database, type of front end application and method of connection between the two systems.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to help you answer such a vague question?

Comment: please edit your question properly. Really confusing to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the field that you'd like to insert data into like this;

```
INSERT INTO Table (field)
VALUES (@datapassedin)
```

It gets more complicated when you want to UPDATE but I don't believe that's your question.

Comment: Thanks. Its exactly what I was looking for

Comment: no worries, feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Check the **[INSERT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)** sintaxis

You can select insert only the columns you want, and will get nulls on the rest

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You essentially do it the same as you'd expect, just that you leave out the irrelevant columns.

`INSERT INTO yourTable (columnToInsertInto) VALUES (DataToInsert)`

Answer (score 2):

When you insert a value to a table, you need to identify values for each-column of that row.
if, column property of "allow-nulls" is YES, then you can insert 1 value, and leave others null. if not, it's not possible.
for existing row, if you want to set a value, use UPDATE.

if you can explain more spesific, i may help more.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert into a table specifying each column name. If you only want to insert a record for the specific column then just specify the name of the column next to the insert into tableName statement.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.yourTableName(column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_3)
VALUES ('25', '1001', 'Notes about this very exciting meeting...')
```